# why I can't open local file in Spark scala on EMR

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I'm using AWS EMR at work. If I launch a spark shell I can run scala commands but can't read in a local file.

For example:

```
scala> val citi = spark.read.textFile("CitiGroup2006")
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: hdfs://ip-10-99-99-99.ec2.internal:8020/user/hadoop/CitiGroup2006;
```

I tried entering the full path of the file but I get the same error. The file is in the same directory where I launched the spark shell. It does however work to load a scala file

```
:load hello.scala
```

Why does "load" work but not spark.read.textFile?

Comment: Did you try with the file ext?

Comment: that file doesn't have an extension. It's a plain text file, readable in Linux.

Comment: Prefix the file with file:/// for files on local fa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not so strong on scala.
but its look like `spark.read.file` read from the HDFS and I guess that your file is on the EMR local. 
you can see files on the HDFS using the command:
`$ hdfs dfs -ls`
and copy files using the `-put`
check out [hadoop copy a local file system folder to HDFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28213116/hadoop-copy-a-local-file-system-folder-to-hdfs)
and [hadoop-common/FileSystemShell](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.7/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#put)

Comment: Yeah, you got it. I had to put the file in HDFS. Thanks!