# Ingest folder with many text files into Hadoop

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

I have a folder on my desktop with 3,000+ small .txt files in it. How can I get that folder into Hadoop with all of the .txt files instead of uploading each one separately?

I am using Ubuntu OS with Hadoop 3.1.2

Comment: Loading the file into HDFS in many ways. This one has detail explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28213116/hadoop-copy-a-local-file-system-folder-to-hdfs

Answer (score 0):

HDFS is not meant to store "small files" of any type. You should compress them into a BZ2 archive, for example, then upload that to HDFS.

Bzip archives are readable by most Hadoop libraries.